# Html.toHtml() doesn't convert RelativeSizeSpan 'ed Text

Tags: android, html, spannable

Here is what i am trying to do,

```
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Shiva");
    s.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    editText.setText(s, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

And on a Click event, i m trying to convert it to HTML, by this code

```
    Log.d("SampleApp",Html.toHtml(editText.getText()));
```

I am expecting some

```
 <h1> or <h2> tag
```

But what i see is this

```
<p dir=ltr>Shiva</p>
```

Kindly help me, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Html.toHtml will return content in `<p>` or `<div>` tag,

Have you look at source code of Html.toHtml ?

Check following code, I pulled that code from latest Android 4.3 build.
you can see that toHtml function call withinHtml and withinHtml function just put div around span and set align attribute.

```
public static String toHtml(Spanned text) {
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        withinHtml(out, text);
        return out.toString();
    } 

private static void withinHtml(StringBuilder out, Spanned text) {
        int len = text.length();

        int next;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i = next) {
            next = text.nextSpanTransition(i, len, ParagraphStyle.class);
            ParagraphStyle[] style = text.getSpans(i, next, ParagraphStyle.class);
            String elements = " ";
            boolean needDiv = false;

            for(int j = 0; j < style.length; j++) {
                if (style[j] instanceof AlignmentSpan) {
                    Layout.Alignment align =
                        ((AlignmentSpan) style[j]).getAlignment();
                    needDiv = true;
                    if (align == Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER) {
                        elements = "align=\"center\" " + elements;
                    } else if (align == Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE) {
                        elements = "align=\"right\" " + elements;
                    } else {
                        elements = "align=\"left\" " + elements;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (needDiv) {
                out.append("<div ").append(elements).append(">");
            }

            withinDiv(out, text, i, next);

            if (needDiv) {
                out.append("</div>");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok. i understand that, in that case, atleast i can expect <p dir=ltr><h1>Shiva</h1></p> since i have relativesize span right?

Comment: Yes, I hope my answer solve your question, If yes plz mark as solved, thx

Answer (score 0):

another way would be using the AbsoluteSizeSpan.class

s.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(14), 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

this would return something like: <font size ="2">Shiva</font>